# Qual a melhor forma de calcular os intervalos "intermediários" entre duas datas

Tags: php, javascript, data, matemática

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Laravel com FullCalendar v4. Ao criar um "evento", esse evendo tem data de execução (dtstart) e data de vencimento (until), contudo haverá eventos intermediários, com base na quantidade de eventos informados.
A questão é: como calcular as datas intermediárias entre 'dtstart' e 'until', ou seja, a dificuldade não é codificar mas achar a fórmula correta.

**Exemplo:**

```
$dtstart = '2019-04-01';
$until   = '2019-05-30';
$eventos = 5;
```

Nesse exemplo, tenho uma diferença de 59 dias (until - dtstart -1). Preciso gerar mais '3' eventos/datas, sendo esses eventos entre 'dtstart' e 'until', de forma distribuidas entre esse intervalo de dadas. Claro que esses valores podem ser outros.

Obrigado!

Comment: Divida a quantidade de dias que possui pelo número de eventos menos 1. Se tem 59 dias para 5 eventos, o intervalo será 59/4. Não é isso? Aí a regra para arredondar é você que decide.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, francamente, não tenho certeza pela simplicidade da sua resposta e até mesmo pelo meu cenário... estava elaborando tantos cálculos, um mais complexo que outro, que já estava ficando perdidão e pensei... não é possivel nao ter um calculo basico para isso. Mas vou tentar de novo com seu modelo.

Comment: Por amostragem, demonstra aparetemente atender a seguinte formula: `$diff_days = $dtstart->diff($until, true)->days; round($diff_days / $events);`. Novamente valeu pela sugestão.

Comment: Nem precisa ser por amostragem, matematicamente é provado que te atenderá em todas as situações.

Comment: Obrigado novamente pela ajuda, sem sua sugestão, talvez estaria preso em cálculos complexos. De qualquer modo, segue para compartilhar qual a solução final para o meu cenário.  `$diff_days = $until->diff($dtstart, true)->days; round(($diff_days - 1) / ($disparo_quant + 1) )`; Um pequeno ajuste no cálculo fez toda a diferença.`